# places maps with geojson in django error

Tags: python, django, maps

i want to show some dynamic places in my web site and i follow this tutorial
 [geojson](http://fle.github.io/easy-webmapping-with-django-leaflet-and-django-geojson.html)

models.py

```
class MushroomSpot(models.Model):
geom = PointField()
description = models.TextField()
picture = models.ImageField()

@property
def popupContent(self):
  return '<img src="{}" /><p><{}</p>'.format(
      self.picture.url,
      self.description)
```

MushroomSpot is the ForeignKey to other models in my model
admin.py

```
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
admin.site.register(MushroomSpot,LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

all work without error code.
but in my admin(administrator page) i cant to add points because dont show me the map.
[administrator page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq5mJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you might need a widget in your form to show the map in the admin portal.

You can try [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet) library, they seem to support [Leaflet maps form widgets.](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet#leaflet-map-forms-widgets)

Comment: i need to create js files and i import in form ?

Comment: i see javascript files but i dont know how to write it and how to import it